# Database connection not established in published asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, web-config, connection-string

I have developed a web application in asp.net , and have published that website in iis 7.
I have given full access to the published folder and it works perfectly.When i browse my published application the login page has been loaded initially. If i fill the details and tried to login **there connection fails.SQL connection has noot been opened**

webConfig i have

```
  <add name="SQLSERVER2008ConString" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=REPOSITY;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and  for opening connection

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
```

here the connection is not getting opened.But it works perfectly in my development environment.But not working after i published the code.
this how i connect my sql in local

[image]

**Note:**

1. Development environment is my system.
2. Used SQL Server 2008 and that is also in my system.
3. Published the website from my system only.

thanks

Comment: first open sqlserver open your database?

Comment: @DenishParvadia : sorry couldnt get you..!

Comment: you use username password in sqlserver?

Comment: Try this `Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=REPOSITY;Trusted_Connection=True;`

Comment: @vallabha i tried.But no use..!!

Comment: is this providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" needed in published webconfig ?? @vallabha

Comment: yes it should be. I tried the following in my case and succeed  `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`

Comment: in myServerAddress i need to give my ip address right.??

Comment: @Coder IpAddress and the server name as well

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
String conString= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLSERVER2008ConString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your SQL Local Login Name is (local) ? Check the name once. But If Yes, then try this: `<add name="SQLSERVER2008ConString" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=REPOSITY;Integrated Security=True" User Id = [ENTER YOUR WINDOWS LOGIN USERNAME];Password = [ENTER YOUR WINDOWS LOGIN PASSWORD]"/>`